Firefox fails to load picture elements with srcset, while Chrome and Edge successfully load photos
I’m attempting to use picture elements for the first time, and I’m trying to figure out what is wrong with my srcset syntax.
Chrome and Edge successfully load photos with the srcset attributes included like this:
<picture style="position: absolute;">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-768.webp,https://example.com/mh-1728.webp 2x,https://example.com/h-1728.webp 3x" media="(max-height: 768px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-1080.webp,https://example.com/h-1728.webp 2x,https://example.com/h-2796.webp 3x" media="(max-height: 864px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-1080.webp,https://example.com/h-2796.webp 2x," media="(max-height: 932px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-2796.webp" media="(min-height: 1081px)">
  <img src="https://example.com/h-768.webp" alt="alt" class="class">
</picture>

Firefox displays the alt text instead of the image, and when hovering over the element in the Inspector, displays the message "Could not load the image", although no errors are logged.
Firefox successfully loads the image if the srcset attributes are removed from the source elements:
<picture style="position: absolute;">
  <source media="(max-height: 768px)">
  <source media="(max-height: 864px)">
  <source media="(max-height: 932px)">
  <source media="(min-height: 1081px)">
  <img src="https://example.com/h-768.webp" alt="alt" class="class">
</picture>

What's the correct syntax for using srcset in Firefox?
Thanks!

Typo in srcset="https://example.com/h-1080.webp,https://example.com/h-2796.webp 2x,". Remove that last comma

I was hoping that was it.  It still works in Chrome and Edge with the trailing comma, but does not work in Firefox with or without the trailing comma.

codepen also fails to load to photo if the srcset attributes are included, and loads the photo successfully without the srcset attributes.

I am unable to reproduce the problem using my own images so please could you create a runnable snippet with images we can use and which you have tested definitely shows the problem.

As an aside, I do not understand the order of your media queries.

Like @AHaworth, I tried to recreate the problem (see Codepen) but, depending on how the images were listed, they loaded or didn’t load the same on Firefox, Chrome, and Edge (on Windows 10). The images loaded properly if I included a space after the comma. Without a space after the comma, the browser combines the first and second image URLs into one invalid URL. I couldn’t find a standard that says a space is required after the comma, but the examples I’ve copied for my designs always had a space.

It was the spaces after the commas.  Firefox and codepen require them.  Chrome and Edge ignore them.  Maybe I misunderstood mozilla's description of the srcset attribute: "Space characters, other than the whitespace separating the URL and the corresponding condition descriptor, are ignored; this includes both leading and trailing space, as well as space before or after each comma. "

I followed up with a second question about the media queries.   My goal is to pick an image resolution based on screen height & pixel density.  I'm open to suggestions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78882613/picking-image-resolution-based-on-screen-height-pixel-density-with-srcset-pic

MDN Picture Tag Reference and MDN Responsive Images Reference. We can however use two attributes — srcset and sizes — to provide several additional source images along with hints to help the browser pick the right one.

Update – Per the HTML standard, an ASCII whitespace is required after the comma – If present, its value must consist of one or more image candidate strings, each separated from the next by a U+002C COMMA character (,). If an image candidate string contains no descriptors and no ASCII whitespace after the URL, the following image candidate string, if there is one, must begin with one or more ASCII whitespace.

I heard back from mozilla.  They will correct the description of the scrset attribute that states "Space characters, other than the whitespace separating the URL and the corresponding condition descriptor, are ignored; this includes both leading and trailing space, as well as space before or after each comma. "
