picking image resolution based on screen height * pixel density with srcset, picture, img html
I'd like to load a set of photos for which the limiting dimension will be height and also consider pixel density.
The images will fill the screen vertically and allow cropping horizontally in portrait orientation.
According to this CSStricks article, browsers automatically adjust srcset w units for pixel density:
https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/
I couldn't find any mention of the pixel density adjustment in the mozilla docs, but srcset doesn't include an h unit, so it looks like picking a resolution based on screen height falls under the category of "art direction", which requires the picture element.
I was able to get this syntax to work, but I'm wondering if there is a more compact syntax for picking resolution based on screen height.
Also, there is something I don't understand about mozilla's definition of the srcset attribute, which states, "Space characters, other than the whitespace separating the URL and the corresponding condition descriptor, are ignored; this includes both leading and trailing space, as well as space before or after each comma. "
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset
I learned here that Firefox and codepen require whitespace after commas, while Chrome and Edge ignore this whitespace:
Firefox fails to load picture elements with srcset, while Chrome and Edge successfully load photos
I'm interested to learn if there is a more compact syntax than this one that will allow picking a resolution based on screen height * pixel density:
<picture style="position: absolute;">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-768.webp, https://example.com/mh-1728.webp 2x, https://example.com/h-1728.webp 3x" media="(max-height: 768px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-1080.webp, https://example.com/h-1728.webp 2x, https://example.com/h-2796.webp 3x" media="(max-height: 864px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-1080.webp, https://example.com/h-2796.webp 2x" media="(max-height: 932px)">
  <source srcset="https://example.com/h-2796.webp" media="(min-height: 1081px)">
  <img src="https://example.com/h-768.webp" alt="alt" class="class">
</picture>


I still don't understand your media queries - what happens between 932 and 1081 - are you happy with just the default img in that space? Am I misunderstanding your requirement?

You're right.  The min-height should be min-height: 933px.  Thanks.  This structure is a combination of picture elements recommended here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images and here: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/responsive-images-101-part-9-image-breakpoints/ but based on height, not width.

I’m not sure “Chrome and Edge ignore this whitespace” is correct. When I run the code locally from the Pen I created, Edge requests an image with a combined URL: https://placehold.co/1201x768.webp,https://placehold.co/1202x1728.webp Adding the space fixes it on all three browsers. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a working code snippet that demonstrates the error — I wouldn’t worry about creating a more compact syntax. This is what the picture element is for. The savings comes from loading a size-appropriate image.

The code above adds spaces after the commas.  My question here is about the best way to pick a resolution based on screen height, instead of width.
